# IE 11 Script1002 Array.Filter(x => ...) (Arrow functions)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

I get a error message in **IE11** but not in chrome the error is:

> Script1002 Syntax error

My code is as follows

```
var selectedRoles = vm.roles.filter(x => x.id === role.id);
```

The line and column number of the error suggest that it is the arrow function `=>` that **IE11** does not like. However it works fine in **Chrome** and **Edge**

Comment: IE11 doesn't support arrow function

Answer (score 109, accepted):

ie 11 not support [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

try

```
var selectedRoles = vm.roles.filter(function(x) { return x.id === role.id; });
```

Answer (score 4):

IE not supported [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) check [browser compatibility here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility). If you want IE support then use  the normal function instead.

```
var selectedRoles = vm.roles.filter(function(x) {
  return x.id === role.id
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The arrow function is not supported yet in IE 11. You can refer to these compatibity table: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ to get an overview what is suuported where and to what extent in a detailed fashion.

Use pollyfills or a PRE-ES6 compatible code, e.g.

```
var selectedRoles = vm.roles.filter(function(x) {
   return x.id === role.id
});
```