# IE11 - How to solve Syntax Error mouseEvent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mouseevent

I get a syntax error in the mouseEvent in IE11

```
const mouseEvent = e => {
    if (!e.toElement && !e.relatedTarget) {
        document.removeEventListener('mouseout', mouseEvent);
                    
    }
};
```

is there a solution for all browsers? an if query with navigator.userAgent was unsuccessful

Comment: IE11 doesn't support arrow functions `=>` - use a "normal" anonymous function.  https://caniuse.com/?search=arrow%20functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of arrow functions for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241267/equivalent-of-arrow-functions-for-ie) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595690/ie-11-script1002-array-filterx-arrow-functions

Comment: ahhh thx 4 help